# Encryption after Symlinks are made

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, disk-encryption

I wanted to ask before I did something really stupid. So, here it goes...

.

Here's the components I will be referencing:

- "LinuxOS" Partition (dedicated disk; no other partitions on the disk)
- "MyFiles" Partition (dedicated disk; no other partitions on the disk)
- Encryption
- Symlinks

.

Here's the setup:

- "LinuxOS" only has the OS.
- "LinuxOS" has symlinks pointing to folders on "MyFiles".

.

**My Question:** Will encrypting the entire disk with "LinuxOS" on it then also encrypt all the contents that it's symlinks point to on the "My Files" partition and/or disk?

Comment: It depends on whether the software you use to encrypt the "LinuxOS" disk follows symlinks. To test this, you may create two new (small) partitions, mount them as filesystems, and put a file in one and a symlink in the other that points to it. Then, encrypt the partition with the symlink and see if the file that the symlink points to gets encrypted.

Comment: Partition-level encryption (LUKS) or encryption of specific directory trees?

Comment: I'm thinking LUKS via TPM.